# NSFetchedResultsController update every minute with observable NSDate of today?

Tags: core-data, nsdate, nspredicate, nsfetchedresultscontroller, key-value-observing

I have a list of results showing on the UI for the current NSDate. Every minute, I need this list and another field to update (although a change may not occur every minute).

I am using an NSFetchedResultsController with an NSPredicate and a static variable holding the NSDate at the time.

Now I could simply reset the NSFetchedResultsController every minute, but with an observable coredata set that seems a little crude.

Is there a way to make that NSDate variable observable, such that coredata will reevaluate the NSPredicate when it's updated?

```
var today: NSDate = NSDate()
predicate: NSPredicate(format: "startTime > %@ AND endTime < %@" /* AND classCodeNumber != nil" */, today.startOfDay(), today.endOfDay())!...
```

With passing time, this predicate should change the set of data shown.

Comment: Are you sure you need it to update every minute? Would it not just be better to update the view when core data changes? Nsfetchedresultscobtroller is built for this already with its delegate methods.

Comment: Fogmeiser is absolutely correct. Once a fetch is performed the fetched results controller observes the context for changes. There is no need to refetch or poll on some time interval. When something changes, the fetched results controller will tell you.

Comment: The context data isn't changing every minute. Time is. The query predicate is based on the current time, and every minute the results may be different. The results are different every minute, not the source data.